# How to filter *.abc from *.abcd files when using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, filtering, openfiledialog

I have created an OpenFileDialog object, called openFileDialog.

When calling openFileDialog.ShowDialog I want to be able to select files having only the extension **".abc"** and not **".abcd"**.

Using the property:

```
this.openFileDialog.Filter = "*.abc";
```

does not work. ".abcd" files can also be selected.

Here is the full code:

```
var openFileDialog = GetOpenFileDialog("abc",
                                       "*.abc",
                                       "anything (*.abc)|*.abc",
                                       "Select abc file to import...");

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{ DoJob(); }
```

Where GetOpenFileDialog is:

```
private OpenFileDialog GetOpenFileDialog(string defaultExt, string fileName, string filter, string title)
    {
        return new OpenFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = defaultExt,
                FileName = fileName,
                Filter = filter,
                Title = title,
            };
    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: There's another post like that [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437914/filtering-file-names-getting-abc-without-abcd-or-abcde-and-so-on?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the filter option of the OpenFileDialog

```
this.openFileDialog.Filter = "abc files (*.abc)|*.abc"
```

Comment: Removed my comment but heres the [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) +1

Comment: @Sayse Your link is for WPF, but I think this is Windows Form in which case it would be [`Filter` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - OpenFileDialog is the same regardless isn't it?

Comment: @Sayse Possibly so. Your linked seemed to be a Silverlight version in class `System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog` in assembly `System.Windows.dll`. My link seems to be a .NET Framework version in class `System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog` (from which `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` inherits) in assembly `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. Not sure if they are equally relevant to the asker, but the syntax of the string seems to be the same in both documentations.

Comment: @FreddieH Using the Filter property does not work. I can still choose ".abcd" files

Comment: @mirelvlad instead of passing just `"*.abc"` to the filter use `"abc files (*.abc)|*.abc"` as filter. It should work

Comment: @mirelvlad I tested your code and got the same thing. It worked when I passed a `null` value to the filename

Answer (score 0):

There is simply a filter property for FileDialogs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx

Comment: I set the this.openFileDialog.Filter = "*.abc" but I still can choose ".abcd" files

Comment: @mirelvlad "*.abc" returns files having an extension of .abc, .abcd, .abcde, .abcdef, and so on unfortunately.